# Using Runtime Generate Generic Type to Filter Using OfType<>

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

So dug around the Google and just can't seem to word this properly to find my answer to here I am.

this is what i currently have

Using these interfaces I will pass in a list of IConversionHelper

```
namespace InvestOne.Response.Mapper.Interfaces
{
    public interface IConversionHelper
    {
        bool CanHelp(object value, Type destinationType);
    }

    public interface IConversionHelper<out T> :IConversionHelper
    {
        T Convert(object value);
    }
}
```

Like So

```
    public Mapper(IEnumerable<IConversionHelper> conversionHelpers)
    {
        _conversionHelpers = conversionHelpers;
    }
```

Then when mapping will use these helpers like so

```
            var propType = prop.PropertyType;
            var value = @from[spectraCode.Code];
            var conversionType = typeof (IConversionHelper<>).MakeGenericType(propType);
            var conversionHelpers = _conversionHelpers.OfType<conversionType>();
```

the issue is in the last line and i understand the problem being that generics need to be at compile time and right now its not. so trying to find something similar to creating the generic type at run time only in this case filter out at run time.

the ideal solution would give me the generic runtime equivalent to

```
  var conversionHelpers = _conversionHelpers.OfType<IConversionHelper<DateTime>>()
```

if the property type was a `DateTime`so that later i can call `helper.Convert(value)`

Comment: You might be able to produce what you want with a manually created expression tree. Sorry that I can't give you more details now, but that might get you pointed into the right direction. Look into [`MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod.aspx)

Comment: @FrankJ, good suggestion but need to get to a more defined type so that i can call helper<type>.Convert(). Would be a lot easier for me to do with an IoC container but this will be part of an add on lib im building so it cant really have dependencies to the container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A much easier solution would be to use `Where`:

```
var propType = prop.PropertyType;
var value = @from[spectraCode.Code];
var conversionType = typeof (IConversionHelper<>).MakeGenericType(propType);
var conversionHelpers = _conversionHelpers.Where(x => conversionType.IsAssignableFrom(x.GetType()));
```

Of course, the resulting sequence won't be of type `IEnumerable<IConversionHelper<DateTime>>`, but since you don't know the type at compile time anyway, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Would this result in a list of objects of type == conversion type?

Comment: @workabyte, it will result in sequence of type `IEnumerable<IConversionHelper>`, where each item is actually of type `IConversionHelper<DateTime>`

Comment: :/ i need to get access to the convert method that lives in the IConversionHelper<T> , The final cast is really the heart of this question as the cast to type something at run time is the hurdle im not sure how to get over. Answer is still great, hope you can assist with this final pc

Comment: @workabyte, that doesn't make sense; if you don't know the generic type parameter at compile time, how can you write code that calls a method defined in the generic interface?

Comment: may want to throw this in your answer but looking around a little more i found i could use dynamic var type and knowing that ll helpers would be of typed `IConversionHelper<T>` i am able to call the convert method so the last line looks like this `dynamic conversionHelpers = _conversionHelpers.FirstOrDefault(x => conversionType.IsAssignableFrom(conversionType) && x.CanHelp(value, propType));`